# Custom sorting a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Say I have a list of dicts like this:

```
sizes = [
    {
        'doc_count': 86, 
        'key': 'M'
    }, 
    {
        'doc_count': 85, 
        'key': 'XL'
    }, 
    {
        'doc_count': 84, 
        'key': 'L'
    }, 
    {
        'doc_count': 84, 
        'key': 'XXL'
    }, 
    {
        'doc_count': 66, 
        'key': 'S'
    }, 
    {
        'doc_count': 66, 
        'key': 'XXXL'
    }
]
```

What would be the most efficient way to sort it according to the pre-defined list: `'S'`, `'M'`, `'L'`, `'XL'`, `'XXL'`?  (perhaps it's more "ordering" than sorting)

I know I could just do something like:

```
new_list = []
size_map = ['S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL']
for size in size_map:
    for i in range(len(sizes)):
        if size in sizes[i].values():
            new_list.append( { 'key': size, 'doc_count': sizes[i]['doc_count'] } )
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way.  Tried tinkering with some list comprehension but I can't get anything to work yet.  Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: look if this fiddle fits your needs - https://repl.it/Epi9

Comment: that works well!  thanks for doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sorting a list, I recommend the builtin `sorted()` function, or the list method `list.sort()`. To specify an non-standard sort order, use the `key=` keyword:

```
size_map = {'S':1,'M':2,'L':3,'XL':4,'XXL':5,'XXXL':6}
new_list = sorted(sizes, key=lambda x:size_map[x['key']])
```

Alternatively, you could use the index of your original `size_map` list as the sort key:

```
size_map = ['S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL']
new_list = sorted(sizes, key=lambda x:size_map.index(x['key']))
```

But, for sufficiently large `size_map` arrays, using a `dict` will go faster.

Note that [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) encourages the use of `key=` instead of `cmp=`:

> In general, the `key` and `reverse` conversion processes are much faster than specifying an equivalent `cmp` function.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a comparison function and call sorted() like this:

```
sorted_sizes = sorted( sizes, cmp=compFunc )
```

compFunc() could be like this:

```
def compFunc( item1, item2 ) :
    size_map = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL']
    if size_map.index(item1['key']) > size_map.index(item2['key']) :
        return 1
    elif size_map.index(item1['key']) < size_map.index(item2['key']) :
        return -1
    else :
        return 0
```

For the built in function *sorted()* see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: `cmp` is deprecated. Use `key`